# Installation of apache cordova package in vs 2013 - android sdk

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I try to install the feature of apache cordova in vs 2013.

I downloaded and run the `vs2013mda_0.3.exe` again to install Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.0

I left it to install until the half of installation which seemed to me it was stack in the step of Android SDK. So I made a reboot.

And after that it gave me a message that I could not continue the installation but I could do it if I go to [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133) and execute the commands.

I tried the first one on cmd but it gives but back this message `The system is unable to locate the specified disk path.`

What can I do?

Comment: I am the administrator to my computer.

Comment: Run all the 4 commands, one of them will succeed if you have older version of tool.

Comment: @Abhishek-MSFT I made a histore restore and I try to install again the http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42675 but it stacks to the Android sdk for more than one hour. Why?